# Running code from SICP section 3.5.4 with DrRacket

Tags: scheme, sicp, racket

I'm having trouble running an example code from SICP (Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs) Section 3.5.4 (Streams and Delayed Evaluation); the SICP section can be found here: http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-24.html#%_sec_3.5.4.

I'm using DrRacket version 5.2.1, set up with the SICP support language by Neil Van Dyke (**SICP PLaneT 1.17**), which can be found here: http://www.neilvandyke.org/racket-sicp/#%28part._installation%29.

The code, shown below, makes use of streams. With the environment set up as above, the procedures `cons-stream`, `force` and `delay` are already available from DrRacket. But `stream-car` and `stream-cdr` weren't available; so, I had to define them. In the code below, I also define some generic stream functions: `stream-map`, `stream-ref`, `add-streams` and `scale-stream`.

The whole code I'm trying to make work is the following. It includes a procedure to solve first-order differential equations numerically (`solve`), using an integration procedure (`integral`), which uses a delayed argument (`delayed-integrand`); these procedures come from Section 3.5.4.

```
(define (stream-car stream) (car stream))
(define (stream-cdr stream) (force (cdr stream)))
(define (stream-map proc . argstreams)
  (if (stream-null? (car argstreams))
      the-empty-stream
      (cons-stream
       (apply proc (map stream-car argstreams))
       (apply stream-map
              (cons proc (map stream-cdr argstreams))))))
(define (stream-ref s n)
  (if (= n 0)
      (stream-car s)
      (stream-ref (stream-cdr s) (- n 1))))

(define (add-streams s1 s2)
  (stream-map + s1 s2))

(define (scale-stream stream factor)
  (stream-map (lambda (x) (* x factor)) stream))

(define (integral delayed-integrand initial-value dt)
  (define int
    (cons-stream initial-value
                 (let ((integrand (force delayed-integrand)))
                   (add-streams (scale-stream integrand dt)
                                int))))
  int)

(define (solve f y0 dt)
  (define y (integral (delay dy) y0 dt))
  (define dy (stream-map f y))
  y)
```

When I put the definitions above in DrRacket and click Run, no error occurs. However, an error occurs when I try to execute the following line in the interactions window:

```
(stream-ref (solve (lambda (y) y) 1 0.001) 1000)
```

The error message is:

```
mcar: expects argument of type <mutable-pair>; given #<undefined>
```

When this error occurs, DrRacket highlights the body of the definition of the procedure `stream-car`, as shown in the picture below:

[image: DrRacket error]

---

What is causing this error? I have already used the stream procedures above in previous examples (`stream-car`, `stream-cdr`, `stream-map`, `add-streams` and `scale-stream`) and they worked. The `integral` procedure also works when I use it outside of the `solve` procedure; for example, if I define `(define ones (cons-stream 1 ones))` and then I define `(define s (integral (delay ones) 1 1))` and then I execute `(stream-ref s 1000)`, it correctly gives the output `1001`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error you're reporting is rather weird, I can't see where `mcar` is being used - or mutable state for that matter. Try this setup, it works for me without using Neil Van Dyke's support language:

```
#lang racket

(define the-empty-stream '())

(define (stream-null? stream)
  (null? stream))

(define-syntax cons-stream
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((cons-stream head tail)
     (cons head (delay tail)))))

(define (stream-car stream)
  (car stream))

(define (stream-cdr stream)
  (force (cdr stream)))

; ... the rest is the same as in your question
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But strangely, when I run the same command ``(stream-ref (solve (lambda (y) y) 1 0.001) 1000)`` with this set up, I also get an error: ``force: reentrant promise |...mentos\sicp\3-77.rkt:14:16|``. Apparently, this occurs in the phase where ``stream-cdr`` is executed.

Comment: Change the language, instead of SICP choose "determine language from source" and try again

Comment: I changed the language previously, but I must have done something else wrong. I tried again and now it worked. Thank you for your help.